# Binding name in type signature using DataKind

Tags: haskell, syntax, type-systems

So, I finally found a task where I could make use of the new `DataKinds` extension (using ghc 7.4.1). Here's the `Vec` I'm using:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Show)

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
    Nil :: Vec Z a
    Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

Now, for convenience I wanted to implement `fromList`. Basically no problem with simple recursion/fold -- but I can't figure out how to give it the correct type. For reference, this is the Agda version:

```
fromList : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (xs : List A) → Vec A (List.length xs)
```

My Haskell approach, using the syntax I saw [here](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Data-Kinds-and-superfluous-in-my-opinion-constraints-contexts-td5689436.html):

```
fromList :: (ls :: [a]) -> Vec (length ls) a
fromList [] = Nil 
fromList (x:xs) = Cons x (fromList xs)
```

This gives me a `parse error on input 'a'`. Is the syntax I found even correct, or have they changed it? I also added some more extensions which are in the code in the link, which didn't help either (currently I have `GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances`).

My other suspicion was that I just can't bind polymorphic types, but my test for this:

```
bla :: (n :: Nat) -> a -> Vec (S n) a
bla = undefined
```

failed, too, with `Kind mis-match Expected kind 'ArgKind', but 'n' has kind 'Nat'` (don't really know what that means).

Could anyone help me with a working version of `fromList` and also clarify the other issues? Unfortunately, `DataKinds` isn't documented very well yet and seems to assume that everybody using it has profound type theory knowledge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell, unlike Agda, does not have dependent types, so there is no way to do exactly what you want.  Types cannot be parameterized by value, since Haskell enforces a phase distinction between runtime and compile time.  The way `DataKinds` works conceptually is actually really simple: data types are **promoted** to kinds (types of types) and data constructors are promoted to types.

```
 fromList :: (ls :: [a]) -> Vec (length ls) a
```

has a couple of problems: `(ls :: [a])` does not really make sense (at least when you are only faking dependent types with promotion), and `length` is a type variable instead of a type function.  What you want to say is

```
 fromList :: [a] -> Vec ??? a
```

where `???` is the length of the list.  The problem is that you have no way of getting the length of the list at compile time... so we might try

```
 fromList :: [a] -> Vec len a
```

but this is wrong, since it says that `fromList` can return a list of any length.  Instead what we want to say is

```
 fromList :: exists len. [a] -> Vec len a
```

but Haskell does not support this.  Instead

```
 data VecAnyLength a where
     VecAnyLength :: Vec len a -> VecAnyLength a 

 cons a (VecAnyLength v) = VecAnyLength (Cons a v)

 fromList :: [a] -> VecAnyLength a
 fromList []     = VecAnyLength Nil
 fromList (x:xs) = cons x (fromList xs)
```

you can actually use a `VecAnyLength` by pattern matching, and thus getting a (locally) psuedo-dependently typed value.

similarly,

```
bla :: (n :: Nat) -> a -> Vec (S n) a
```

does not work because Haskell functions can only take arguments of kind `*`.  Instead you might try

```
data HNat :: Nat -> * where
   Zero :: HNat Z
   Succ :: HNat n -> HNat (S n)

bla :: HNat n -> a -> Ven (S n) a
```

which is even definable

```
bla Zero a     = Cons a Nil
bla (Succ n) a = Cons a (bla n a)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This makes me start to really understand `DataKinds` -- they mislead me a bit, it seems. Indeed, at the beginning, I thought that I'd need the existentially quantified version, but the dependent type looked much more like what I actually wanted the type to express. Still, where does the binding syntax with `(a :: X) -> Y` come from? I've seen that in some places now.

Comment: For example, it is used [here](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Data-Kinds-and-superfluous-in-my-opinion-constraints-contexts-td5689436.html), and I think also [here](http://www.typesandotherdistractions.com/2012/02/fun-with-xpolykinds-polykinded-folds.html).

Comment: I think most of what you have is code at the term level `\ (a :: X) -> y` and/or stuff involving `PolyKinds`.  For example: `data Box a = Box` and `bla :: Box (n :: Nat) -> a -> Vec n a`

Answer (score 4):

You can use some typeclass magic here (see [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) for more):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, FlexibleInstances
  , NoMonomorphismRestriction, FlexibleContexts #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Show)

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Nil :: Vec Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a

instance Show (Vec Z a) where
  show Nil = "."

instance (Show a, Show (Vec m a)) => Show (Vec (S m) a) where
  show (Cons x xs) = show x ++ " " ++ show xs

class FromList m where
  fromList :: [a] -> Vec m a

instance FromList Z where
  fromList [] = Nil

instance FromList n => FromList (S n) where
  fromList (x:xs) = Cons x $ fromList xs

t5 = fromList [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but this not realy solve the problem:

```
> :t t5
t5 :: (Num a, FromList m) => Vec m a
```

Lists are formed at runtime, their length is not known at compile time, so the compiler can't infer the type for `t5`, it must be specified explicitly:

```
*Main> t5

<interactive>:99:1:
    Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraint:
      (FromList m0) arising from a use of `t5'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: t5
    In an equation for `it': it = t5
*Main> t5 :: Vec 'Z Int
*** Exception: /tmp/d.hs:20:3-19: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fromList

*Main> t5 :: Vec ('S ('S ('S 'Z))) Int
1 2 3 *** Exception: /tmp/d.hs:20:3-19: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fromList

*Main> t5 :: Vec ('S ('S ('S ('S ('S 'Z))))) Int
1 2 3 4 5 .
*Main> t5 :: Vec ('S ('S ('S ('S ('S ('S ('S 'Z))))))) Int
1 2 3 4 5 *** Exception: /tmp/d.hs:23:3-40: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fromList
```

Languages ​​with dependent types have maps from terms to types, types can be formed dynamically at runtime too, so this problem does not exist.

Comment: Types can be 'formed dynamically at runtime' in Haskell, e.g. `runtimetype :: Show a =>  a -> Integer -> String; runtimetype x n = case n of { 0 -> show x ; _ -> runtimetype (Just x) (n-(1::Integer)) ; main = interact $ (++"\n") . runtimetype () . read ` This will print a thing of a different type   for every valid integer it reads from stdin.  Here is hugs executing it http://ideone.com/dAK0K

Comment: Here's a better example, it given a string of length n it prints an n-tuple with the characters http://ideone.com/mcQfl It is a bit like the 'fromList' the op wanted.

Comment: @applicative this is interesting. However, different types appear in the argument here, but `fromList` have term -> type (well, a data kind `Nat`) dependency in the result. I found that `HList` includes a definition for maps from heterogeneous collections to homogeneous, but not the definition of inverse.

Comment: Of course yes, that is the difference; it was the limited point about 'run time' vs. 'compile time' that I was addressing. In any case I wasn't really objecting, just suggesting the matter is hard to formulate.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the previous answers :

- value level, from `[a]` to `exist n. Vec n a`
- value to typed value, from `[a]` to `Vec 5 a`, where *you* have to provide a specific `n`.

A variant of the 1st transform, goes like

```
reify :: [a] -> (forall (n::Nat). Proxy n -> Vec n a -> w) -> w
reify [] k = k (Proxy @ 'Z) Nil
reify (x:xs) k = reify xs (\(_ :: Proxy n) v -> k (Proxy @ ('S n)) (Cons x v))
```

It still goes from a value `[a]` to a typed value `Vec n a` in which `n` is (statically) quantified. This is similar to the `VecAnyLength` approach, without introducing an actual datatype to perform quantification.

The `proxy` here is to explicit the `n` as a `Nat`. it can be removed from the code and `n` left silent, appearing only in the type `Vec n a`, and not provided to the values constructed, as it is in `Proxy @ ('S n)`.